# How to show custom server errors in UI using Plupload and Symfony3

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, file-upload, plupload

### INTRODUCTION

In order to upload multiple files to the server I am using:

1. Symfony v3.2.6
2. [OneUpUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)
3. [OneUpFlysystemBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle)
4. [Plupload file uploading library](http://www.plupload.com)

### NOTE

Please note that: this configuration works without a hitch for single and multiple file uploads. It just does not show custom server errors in the clients browser.

### TARGET

I would like to show `file exists` error in UI

### PROBLEM

I am using validator to restrict some uploadable files.

At the moment files that validator restricts are not uploaded (ValidationException is beeing trown).

I do not know how to make `Plupload` to show `file already exist` errors.

### CODE

My template with relevant javascript code

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/plupload/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css') }}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/plupload/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css') }}" media="screen" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="box-upload">
        <div id="uploader">
            <p>Your browser doesn't have HTML5 support.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/browserplus/browserplus.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plupload/plupload.full.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.2.4.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plupload/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plupload/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plupload/i18n/lv.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';

        $(function()
        {
            var uploader;

            uploader = $("#uploader");

            uploader.plupload(
            {
                // General settings
                runtimes: 'html5',
                url: "{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}",
                multi_selection: true,

                // Maximum file size
                max_file_size: '5mb',

                chunk_size: '5mb',

                // Specify what files to browse for
                filters: [
                    {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,jpeg,png,gif"},
                    {title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip,7z"},
                    {title: "Pdf files", extensions: "pdf"},
                    {title: "Binary files", extensions: "bin"},
                    {title: "Text files", extensions: "txt"},
                    {title: "Media files", extensions: "avi"}
                ],

                // Rename files by clicking on their titles
                rename: true,

                // Sort files
                sortable: true,

                // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
                dragdrop: true,

                // Views to activate
                views: {
                    list: true,
                    thumbs: false, // Show thumbs
                    active: 'list'
                }
            });

            var $uploader = uploader.plupload('getUploader');

            // Add Clear Button
            var $button = $("<button>"+ plupload.translate("Clear list") + "</button>").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-trash"}}).button("disable").appendTo('.plupload_buttons');

            // Clear Button Action
            $button.click(function()
            {
                removeErrorMessages();
                $uploader.splice();
                $(".plupload_filelist_content").html('');
                $button.button("disable");
                return true;
            });

            // Clear Button Toggle Enabled
            $uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function ()
            {
                if ($uploader.files.length > 0)
                {
                    $button.button("enable");
                }
                else
                {
                    $button.button("disable");
                }
            });

            // Clear Button Toggle Hidden
            $uploader.bind('StateChanged', function ()
            {
                if ($uploader.state == plupload.STARTED)
                {
                    $button.hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    $button.show();
                }
            });

            // Clear Button Toggle Hidden
            $uploader.bind('Browse', function ()
            {
                removeErrorMessages();
                $uploader.splice();

            });

            $uploader.bind('Error', function(uploader, error)
            {
                console.error(error.message);
                console.log(error.message);
            });

            function removeErrorMessages()
            {
                $(".ui-state-error").remove();
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

My validator

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\ValidationEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Exception\ValidationException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class AllowedMimeTypeValidationListener
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    private $file_extension_array = [];
    private $file_type_array = [];
    private $banned_files = [];

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onValidate(ValidationEvent $event)
    {
        $ultra_helpers = $this->container->get('app.ultra_helpers');
        $ultra_text = $this->container->get('app.ultra_text');

        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.gif');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.jpg');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.jpeg');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.png');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.zip');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.7z');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.pdf');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.bin');
        array_push($this->file_extension_array, '.txt');

        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'image/gif');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'image/jpg');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'image/jpeg');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'image/png');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'application/zip');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'application/x-7z-compressed');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'application/pdf');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'application/octet-stream');
        array_push($this->file_type_array, 'text/plain');

        array_push($this->banned_files, 'do_not_allow_me_1.txt');
        array_push($this->banned_files, 'do_not_allow_me_3.txt');
        array_push($this->banned_files, 'do_not_allow_me_2.txt');

        $file = $event->getFile();
        $file_extension = '.'. $file->getExtension();
        $file_mime_type = $file->getMimeType();

        $file_info = $ultra_helpers->filterFileInfoFromFilename($file->getClientOriginalName());
        $transliterated_file_name = $ultra_text->transliterateText($file_info['name']);
        $full_file_name = $transliterated_file_name .'.'. $file_info['extension'];

        if (in_array($full_file_name, $this->banned_files))
        {
            throw new ValidationException('error.file_exists');
        }

        // Is file mime type the same as extension mime type
        $mime_type_position = array_search($file_extension, $this->file_extension_array);
        if ($mime_type_position !== false)
        {
            $mime_type_by_extension = $this->file_type_array[$mime_type_position];

            if ($mime_type_by_extension !== $file_mime_type)
            {
                throw new ValidationException('error.mime_type_mismatch');
            }
        }

        // Is file type not in activated file type array
        if (!in_array($file_mime_type, $this->file_type_array))
        {
            throw new ValidationException('error.forbidden_mime_type');
        }
    }
}
```

### FINALLY

What am I missing?

### CONCLUSION

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show error in UI one has to listen to `FileUploaded` event and manually trigger an error (like in code example below).

```
$uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info)
{
    var response;
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(info.response);

    // trigger error manually
    up.trigger("error", {message: "Test error message", code: 12345, details: "Testing errors"});

    // add some CSS class to the corresponding file in UI
    $("#"+ file.id).addClass("highlight-file");
});
```